# Date format handling in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jpa

HI I have a problem in my current Spring +JPA project. My entity object and bean object for web page are same.

1. From web page using jquery i am reading date in (dd-mon-yyyy) format from screen and saving it to database. The field is of Date type in my bean class.
2. During update i am fetching values from database and displaying the same in web page. But this time the date format has chnaged to different fromat(yyyy/mm/dd) on screen.
3. So while saving again i am getting error, as the date format has been changed and i am unable to parse the value received form screen.

So is there any proper way to handle this situation.

Comment: Display it on your page as you would like it saved in the DB? [JSTL formatDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html).

Comment: Hi Beau, Your suggestion worked. 
i wrote like below and it worked,
<span><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" value="${schedule.fromDate}"></fmt:formatDate></span>
I also need to use the formatted value in input field. I tried lots of method by googling. None is working. Can help here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are storing the dates in database as a `DATE` or `DATETIME` type. If so, the value should be a `Date` object in Java. In order to output the date value as `dd-mon-yyyy`, you will need to use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the date object into a string representation in your desired format:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(date);
```

An additional note: for an internal-only API, it doesn't matter what format you choose as long as you are consistent everywhere. But if you are creating something that could one day be exposed publicly, I would suggest that you send/receive date and time value in the ISO8601 format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`. This format is understood by everyone everywhere.

Update:

Based on your comment, I would say add a new method to your bean class:

```
private DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
public String getFromDateString() {
    return dateformat.format(fromDate);
}
```

And then in your JSP, call ${bean.fromDateString}.

Comment: User's requirement is to use date in dd-mon-yyyy format. Using date picker i am getting date in '23-Jan-2015' . In controller class using initBinder i am converting it to Date using SimpleDateFormat and saving it to database. In database the datatype is date. But while reading it agin i am geeting the date in different format as 2015-03-04.

Comment: Then use the SimpleDataFormat#format() method I mentioned and output the date as a string.

Comment: User's requirement is to use date in dd-mon-yyyy format. i am entering date as '23-Jan-2015' in jsp. 
In controller class using initBinder i am using SimpleDateFormat and saving it to database. 
In database the datatype is date. B
ut while reading it again i am getting the date in as 2015-03-04. 
Bean class
private Date fromDate;
 public Date getFromDate() {
  return fromDate;
 }
 public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
  this.fromDate = fromDate;
 }
 This calss is used everywhere, so i am not sure where to refromat the date.
 JSP code-
 <td><span>${schedule.fromDate} </span>